# What is the Mandibles family tree in "The Mandibles: A Family, 2029-2047"?

Tags: the-mandibles-a-family-2029-2047, lionel-shriver

I'm looking for the Mandible's family genealogy as to have a reference while reading the book.

The book is [*The Mandibles: A Family 2029-2047* by Lionel Shriver](http://a.co/awec8G5)

I'm not an English native reader so having this would help me to focus on the story.
If anyone knows where to find one it would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only part way through. I needed the same help but couldn't find anything out there. So I've drawn my own.

I *think* this is it:

[image: Family tree]

Comment: Oh, nice ! That's what I needed! May we try to update it along our reading? I'm almost halfway through. Thanks.